# Is a gift card halal?

Tags: halal-haram, legal

So I just received a gift card (I didn't intend to) for completing something. Is the money in the gift card halal to spend? Or is it haram and I should not use the money in it?

Comment: Please tell us why you think a giftcard may be haram to use.

Comment: Well some sites (such as quora) have answers that using a gift card as if it's real money is ribawi and haram. So I got confused. Any answers?

Comment: I personally don’t think there’s any harm in using them. I mean they’re prepaid cards in general terms. Sometimes someone fills the card with money they supplied with to give to someone else for their own benefit, while others use it without much of a consequence unlike what regular credit cards give off. Correct me if I’m wrong but I don’t think they money they contain is associated with the bank so once it’s finished, that’s it. You don’t have to pay the card back or anything.